# How to start an activity if the power button is pressed (x) no of times in my android app?

Tags: android, logic

Please also explain how it works. This should also work when my app is closed.(it should be running in background)

Comment: you need to register broadcast rceciever for this

Comment: This link may be help to you http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/#comment-4777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register broadcast rceciever for this
This work when app is closed in background

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
private static int countPowerOff = 0;

public MyReceiver ()
{

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
    {    
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
        countPowerOff++;
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    {
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
    {
        Log.e("In on receive", "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
        if (countPowerOff > 2)
        {
            countPowerOff=0;
            Toast.makeText(context, "MAIN ACTIVITY IS BEING CALLED ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i put (countPowerOff > 6) so how many times does the user have to press the power button

Comment: more then 6 times but remember to declare reciever in manifest file to run this

Comment: i tried this but its is not working btw i declared the reciever in the manifest please help

Comment: if you git this code from somewhere please give the link